# Crash when receiving NSUserDefault (saving data)

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, crash, save, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to save some ints for an iPhone game but am getting rather stuck.

I am saving the data as so;

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:careerScore forKey:@"career_score"];
    //Tells the userDefaults to update the data base.
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

when the correct method is called.

The problem I am having is with loading up the variable when the game is first opened. Currently I have;

```
int careerScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] IntegerForKey:@"career_score"];
```

The problem seems to be it can't access this NSUserDefault the first time the game loads (as it doesn't exist until the correct method is called), which then leads to a crash.

How am I meant to grab the integer from there if it does exist, but ignore it if it doesn't? Or is there an easier/better way to save data? I am using cocos2d.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `registerDefaults:` method of the `NSUserDefaults` instance to specify the default values of all your settings.

Comment: When the application finishes loading I now register the Defaults .plist I have created in the Resources folder.


[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Defaults" ofType:@"plist"]]];

However when i run the save commands (quoted in my original question) it doesnt work. When I kill the app it loads up a fresh instead of storing the new ints.

Comment: still crashes when I try to run `int careerScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] IntegerForKey:@"CareerScore"];`

Comment: I have it working now thank you, I shouldn't have had a capital I for integer -.- But you did teach me about registerDefaults: Thanks again!

Comment: When you say it "crashes", are you getting any sort of message in the error console? Are you really calling `IntegerForKey:` and not `integerForKey:` with a lowercase 'i'?

Answer (score 0):

small "i" for integerForKey
30 char.